# Does MySQL use transaction in a single DML modified data with autocommit?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm confused with transaction and autocommit. But there's no documents explains what MySQL autocommit do.

If autocommit on, every `INSERT UPDATE DELETE` statement will take effect immediately. Does MySQL auto start a transaction to do this?

If not, what's MySQL do? What's the difference to transaction?

In my view:

A statement

> INSERT INTO ...

with autocommit on equals to

> START TRANSACTION;
>
> INSERT INTO ...;
>
> COMMIT;

with autocommit off.

The two statements in anytime any condition takes the same action.

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, you have to know, that most MySQL Storage Engines do not support transactions. for example, InnoDB supports, but MyISAM - not.

In InnoDB, you can use transactions by 2 way:

- implicit

  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
  COMMIT;
- explicit

via SET autocommit off

both of them provide the same result